# PuTTy - double SSH + remote command

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, login, putty

I need to do SSH twice:

```
ssh myname@server1
```

and later

```
ssh myname@server2
```

and later I would like to execute a few Bash commands on server2, like e.g. `htop`.

I need all of it to run when clicking PuTTY shortcut. Is it possible? How to do it in a way it will not promt for a password?

Answer (score 1):

One option is [MTPutty](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/). It is a free program that can use Putty in multiple tabs and can run scripts:

> **Automation** (from [this](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/) page):
>   Can automatically login the remote servers and "type" your passwords. Can run any script after login. Can "type" a script in several PuTTY tabs simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this topic: https://superuser.com/questions/587629/how-to-run-a-remote-command-in-putty-after-login-keep-the-shell-running

And this for call command via ssh:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/amp/

For login without password, use ssh-keys.